# load data using provider call while navigating to the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, odoo

I have managed to load data from odoo db, the data can be loaded at first call but after updating or creatinig a new customer in server side `odoo database` nothing happens in my flutter app. the data not loaded in customer screen
i tried to call the provider in `initState` , `setState` but nothing worked for me.

**customer model**

```
class Customer {
  int id;
  String name;


  Customer({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,

  });

  
  factory Customer.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) => Customer(
        name: json["name"],
        id: json["id"],
      );

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "id": id,
      };

}
```

**Customer provider**

```
class CustomerProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  CustomerProvider() {
    loadCustomers().then((customers) {
      _customers = customers;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
  List<Customer> _customers = [];
  List<Customer> get customers => _customers;

  Future getCustomer() async {
      notifyListeners();
      final client = OdooClient('http://localhost:8050');
      await client.authenticate('odoo', 'admin', 'admin');
      var res = await client.callKw({
      'model': 'res.partner',
      'method': 'search_read',
      'args': [],
      'kwargs': {
        'context': {'bin_size': true},
        // 'domain': [
        //   ['id','=',10]
        // ],
        'fields': ['name'],
      },
    });
    return res; 
    
  }

  Future loadCustomers() async {
    notifyListeners();
    final data = await getCustomer();
    _customers = ((data as List).map((i) => Customer.fromJson(i)).toList());
    return _customers;
  }
}
```

**Customer screen**

```
class CustomerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool? isMultiSelection;
  final List<Customer> customers;

  const CustomerPage({
    Key? key,
    this.isMultiSelection = false,
    this.customers = const [],
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomerPageState createState() => _CustomerPageState();
}

class _CustomerPageState extends State<CustomerPage> {
  String text = '';
  bool loading = false;
  List<Customer>? csm;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  bool containsSearchText(Customer customer) {
    final name =  customer.name;
    final textLower = text.toLowerCase();
    final customerLower = name.toLowerCase();

    return customerLower.contains(textLower);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<CustomerProvider>(context, listen: false);
    var allcustomers = provider.customers;
    var customers = allcustomers.where(containsSearchText).toList();

    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: CustomerProvider(),
      child: loading ? const Loading() : Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Selectionner un client'),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60),
          child: SearchWidget(
            text:text,
            hintText: 'Rechercher',
            onChanged: (text) => setState(() => this.text = text),
          )),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: <Color>[Color(0xffC71C24), Color(0xffFDBA45)]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: customers.isEmpty 
      // ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Color(0xffFDBA45),),) 
      ? const Loading()
      : ListView(
        children: customers.map((customer) {
          return CustomerListTileWidget(
            customer: customer, 
            isSelected: false, 
            onSelectedCustomer: selectCustomer
            );
        }).toList(),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: How do you Create or Update customer info on database (server-side)?
Do you mean it's getting updated from out-side of your App?
You have a Provider class, it should be responsible for inserting, updating and loading Model's data, your app can't get notified if data is changing from out-side of your App!

Comment: we have multiples scenarios : 1 - the users of the app only create new customers. 2- ERP administrateur update/create customers from outside the app. 
also, the app can get notified only when I hot reload the app or if I use `providers: [ ChangeNotifierProvider.value( value: CustomerProvider(),),] child :`  instead of the create inside `changeNotifierProvider` call